# Daphne websocket stop responding after somtime

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

Project Specs: Django `3.2.4` , Channels `3.0.5` , Channel-redis `3.4.1` , Daphne `3.0.2`.

I setup a chat system, which communicate using websocket. On page load, everything works fine, but after few seconds only (~20-30 sec), data sending and receiving halt. On refresh page, it again start working. I am not sure, this issue araise from Consumers file or Daphne from my server. below is my `--access-log` of daphne

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIPTX.png)

I tried debugging consumers.py and found nothing, but not sure how to debug daphne or server side issue. Please guide me some checklist to trace issue. I want the connection stay ALIVE for 30 minutes atleast.

For setting up daphne on nginx, i followed [this](https://okbaboularaoui.medium.com/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-daphne-django-channels-on-ubuntu-20-04-b0d24dcc7da9) tutorial.

My Nginx conf is like below:
[Nginx Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s1bL.png)

Answer (score 0):

When the connection drops after around 30s it's probably because Nginx is killing it. I already had this problem a few times myself. The solution is quite simple.

Please set `proxy_read_timeout` to a very high number in your nginx config.
For example 24h.

Your config would look like this then:

```
upstream channels-backend {server localhost:8000;}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir/django_project_dir;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir/django_project_dir;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    }
}
```

Consider reading this:

- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout
- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: I added my Nginx conf image to the question's end. Please check. Restarted Daemon and Nginx. Also Daphne. Still the same Issue.

Comment: Then, I'm out of ideas too, sorry